# Visualize: How many rows do I have left when I remove measures under different thresholds for multiple categories?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using R. I have figured out how to visualize the number of rows remaining when cutting at different thresholds for data belonging to a single category. What I really need is to be able to do that for data belonging to multiple categories so at the end of the day, I can compare them. Here is some sample code to do this with just one category:

```
library(scales)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

mynums <- array(sample(1:900, 600, replace=T), c(100,1))
category <- array(sample(1:3, 600, replace=T), c(100,1))
# the categories are represented by numbers here
mytable <- data.frame(mynums, category, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

cut_left <- filter(mytable, category == 2)
# I chose to demonstrate with category 2, but would like to 
#     systematically do this for all categories

cut_off <- numeric(501)
rows_left <- numeric(501)
for (i in 0:500) {
  cut_off[i + 1] <- i
  v <- cut_left[cut_left$mynums > i,]
  rows_left[i + 1] <- nrow(v)
}
cut <- data.frame(cut_off, rows_left, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

g <- ggplot(data = cut, aes(x = cut_off, y = rows_left)) + 
  geom_line() +

p <- ggplotly(g)
print(p)
```

Here is an image of the output (will vary a little because random numbers):
[image]

The goal is to have one data frame at the end that has a column for the cut-off, a column for number of rows left after the cut-off, and a column that holds the category each piece of data belongs to.

I am currently trying some nested for loops to get it done, but I thought I'd reach out to the community because I'm sure there is a better way that I can't seem to find/think of :)

To be clear, I will be turning whatever works best into a function that will need to work no matter the number of categories or data frame size. While I appreciate hard-coding answers that may help others, I am personally looking for something flexible. Thanks!

Comment: You're actually building the sample distribution function -- see `?ecdf`.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Thanks!